# How to install StatET on Eclipse 4.11.0

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-marketplace, statet

How to install the StatET plugin on Eclipse 4.11.0?
I have been using on older versions of Eclipse for many years. Has it even been released for 4.11.0?

The relevant link: https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/science.statet

Comment: That link suggests there will be release for the upcoming Eclipse 2019-06 release (4.12)

Comment: Update: I switched to VS Code